# CSOM to append a line in a text file

Tags: 2010, powershell, csom, file

Using SharePoint 2010 and `Microsoft.SharePoint.client.dll`.

I am trying to update a text file (basically adding a line at the end of the text file with log details) that is stored in a SharePoint document library.

Is it possible do this with PowerShell CSOM?

I tried to use some code but it's throwing an error while using `SaveBinaryDirect`.

Here is the complete error message:

> Exception calling "SaveBinaryDirect" with "4" argument(s): "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0) for SE to distribute that content. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, consider taking a look at: [How does deleting work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/295232)?